# xaxis/yaxis lines in matlab plot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

couldn't find this:

I would like to plot a line on X and Y axis that always fits to 100% to the width or height of the figure.

```
figure; hold on;
plot(rand(1,100));
line(xlim,[.5 .5],'Color','red');
line([50 50],ylim,'Color','red');
pause(.5)
xlim([1 200]);% lines should now automatically extend
```

with `grid on` it's possible to get a grid that scales automatically, however it seems impossible to only limit the grid to the X/Y axes. Ideas?

[image: bsdf]

after scaling:

[image: asdf]

what I would prefer:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions [`xline`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xline.html)
and [`yline`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/yline.html)
were introduced in MATLAB R2018b, and do exactly as you need.

Furthermore, it is possible to add a (text) label to the line.

Answer (score 0):

```
figure;
plot([1:10]);
set(gca, 'position', [0 0  1 1]);
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it should. It is just a simpler example of figure creation.